# Roberts-Slaney-Bouras integer FFT implementation woes

Tags: c, fft, integer-arithmetic

I've implemented a signal processing FFT algorithm in Python using np.fft (too easy). Now I'm working on doing this in C using an integer algorithm. After some research, I found that one of the most popular integer FFT libraries in C on the internet is the one by Roberts, Slaney, and Bouras which can be found in many places including the second entry [here](http://www.jjj.de/fft/fftpage.html).fft,

There are a few concepts I don't understand and am hoping for guidance.
Specifically, the example script included in the library linked above separates the input signal into two bins, real and imaginary, by putting all of the even indexes of the signal in the first half and the odd indexes in the second half of the signal.

```
for (i=0; i<N; i++){
    x[i] = AMPLITUDE*cos(i*FREQUENCY*(2*3.1415926535)/N);
    if (i & 0x01)            // only odd index
        fx[(N+i)>>1] = x[i]; // N+i >> 1 is len(input)+i/2
    else                     // only even index
        fx[i>>1] = x[i];
}
fix_fftr(fx, log2N, 0);
```

The signal array has not changed length but now contains two of almost the same signal. Then FFT driver function (fix_fftr) takes the entire input signal as an argument and does the exact same thing

```
if (inverse)
    scale = fix_fft(fr, fi, m-1, inverse);
for (int i=1; i<n; i+=2) {
    tt = f[n+i-1];      // even index
    f[n+i-1] = f[i];    // odd index into the second half
    f[i] = tt;          // even index into the first half
}
if (!inverse)
    scale = fix_fft(fr, fi, m-1, inverse);
return scale;
```

whats the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

The first part is computing the twiddle factors, which are constants for a given length FFT and independent of the data.

The second part appears to be part of the data shuffling based on recursive bit-reversed addressing, which is a component within an in-place FFT.